# How to pass multiple parameters to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I'm trying to change the href of my link to make it take two parameters to another function by JS.
This should happen when I click on an element.

Here is my Js function that is not working:

```
function Changehref(idProdukt, idOperation) {


 document.getElementById("deleteIcon").href = "Order/DeleteItem?id=" + idProdukt +   "&operationId=" + idOperation;

}
```

this is my function in my Controller Order

```
   public ActionResult DeleteItem(long idProduct, long idOperation)
    {
        var reg = new ProductRegistry();


        reg.DeleteProductionOrderOperation(SQLConnection, idProduct,idOperation);
        return View("Details");
    }
```

How do I navigate to DeleteItem and send the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you are sending do not match the method signature, so model binding isn't kicking in.

Change this below

```
document.getElementById("deleteIcon").href = "Order/DeleteItem?id=" + idProdukt +   "&operationId=" + idOperation;
```

To

```
document.getElementById("deleteIcon").href = "Order/DeleteItem?idProduct=" + idProdukt +   "&idOperation=" + idOperation;
```